# How do I read/parse all yaml files in a directory?

Tags: python, python-2.7, yaml, pyyaml

Well, I am trying to read a collection of `utf-8` yaml files in a directory with `python 2.7` and `pyyaml`. 
I tried to use `os.listdir(os.getcwd())`, but it actually returns a list of files and I need to read the files and exhibit the content (key, value).
The directory only has yaml files and pyyaml library is already installed.

All the content of the yaml files are similar to this:

```
fruits:
 - bananas
 - apples
 - grapes
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this:

content of `demo_file1.yaml`:

```
fruits:
  - bananas
  - apples
  - grapes
```

content of `demo_file2.yaml`:

```
veg:
  - cauli
  - lady finger
  - tomato
```

Code:

```
import yaml
import glob

files = glob.glob("/path/to/directory/*.yaml") # list of all .yaml files in a directory 

def read_yaml_file(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as stream:
        try:
            print(yaml.safe_load(stream))
        except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
            print(exc)

for file in files:
    read_yaml_file(file)
```

output:

```
{'fruits': ['bananas', 'apples', 'grapes']}
{'veg': ['cauli', 'lady finger', 'tomato']}
```